Vue 3 app - memory consumption keeps going up
I'm facing a challenge in figuring out what's causing the Vue app to consume a lot of memory. There are detached elements in the heap snaps from unmounted components.
Here's the setup:

Vue 3.5.12
Vue-route 4.x
Vite: 5.1.1
vite-plugin-vue-devtools ^7.5.3

Here's a simplified use case
Use case: Build an app for HVAC company supervisor role to monitor service-requests(SR) from all customers

Each SR is a multi-step workflow
App has a dashboard view to display all SRs from the DB

Scenario: There are 1000+ SRs to be listed on the dashboard, as the user navigates between views of a SR and goes back to the Dashboard, the memory use spikes by 100s of MB and sometimes hits 1-2GB  - Chrome's memory meter for the tab.
Initial render:

First visit to the dashboard:

Navigating away from Dashboard (component tree is unmounted but objects are not garbage collected)

Note:

There's no use of <keep-alive>
All views/pages are rendered using <router-view>
All components are SFC Composition APIs
Pinia for state management

Here's Chrome Heap snapshots comparison:
Snapshot 2 - page1 initial state
Snapshot 3 - navigation: page1 -> Dashboard -> page1

All Detached elements:

Apologies, as I cannot provide a small working app to demonstrate this issue. The app in question is a corporate one.
All components are correctly getting unmounted

I added console stmts to onBeforeUnmount hook in all concerned components and they all get executed, which means the components are being unmounted but not getting garbage collected.

I was expecting the memory object from unmounted components will get cleaned up, but it isn't happening.
Any clue?

This likely means that there's a memory leak. It's impossible to say what is the problem without checking the app and debugging it
